# Submit form to new window only when specific submit button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form, which has a few different submit buttons on it all doing different things with the same post data.

Lets say for simplicity sake the form looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="1,2,3,4" />
  <input type="submit" id="picking" name="picking" value="Picking" />
  <input type="submit" id="shipping" name="shipping" value="Shipping" />
  <input type="submit" id="invoice" name="invoice" value="Invoice" />
</form>
```

At the moment the form submits to itself and I work out server side which submit button is pressed, build a URL from the POST data, then do a PHP redirect to what I need to go. This works fine.

However, I am looking for the form to post its data to a new window, but only when  "invoice" is clicked. This rules out just adding `target="_blank"` to the form, as the other 2 buttons would submit to new pages as well.

I also can't split the form into 3 different forms as the data is a lot more complex than the above, and a lot of it is input by the user.

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript/JQuery? If so, where would I start?

Thanks

Comment: If you build this with javascript requirement in mind, your form will be useless to people who have disabled javascript.

Comment: Though if you do need to do it with javascript, on the onclick event - do a `form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");` before submitting.

Comment: @Straseus being reliant on Javascript isn't an issue. It's for something that I know exactly who will be using it, and so know they have JS on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could you not add target blank to the form when invoice is clicked?:

```
$("#invoice").click(function(){
  $('#form_id').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on("click","#invoice",function(){
      $('#form_id').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click handler to the correct submit button.

```
$('#invoice').on('click', function(){
    //doStuff
});
```

This will allow you to control the action of #invoice without affecting the others.

Comment: It's the **doStuff** part that your answer should address.